# Implementing typescript interface in webstorm gets "not implemented method" errors

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have an interface (`Worker`, actually) implemented for some classes. But WebStorm gets me a bunch of errors looking like this:

[image: Typescript interface implementing errors in WebStorm]

Why does it happen? I do not have this methods and properties in my interface. And it is compiled by npm tsc without any problem. Is it a bug?

**Info**:

- **IDE**: WebStorm 2016.1.1.
- **Module system**: es6.
- **Compiling target**: es6.
- Interface is placed in single file.

Comment: @Kutyel, still 6 minutes to be able to approve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your interface, it seems that `Worker` could be some other kind of already-defined interface (maybe a super class of `WebWorker`)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Worker is used for HTML5 Web Workers. 
That is why you get errors that hint you to implement all the Worker interface methods.

You can try renaming your interface